# two validation buttons in different usercontrol.ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I need to validate two separate group one by click button1,and another one is click button2
Two buttons are in separate user controls implemented in same page ,the validation to the first user control also validates the second one,i give the validation group for both user controls separately it don't work.
please help me...

the below code contains two user controls,that having the one button is in                    `< uc1:UCEditRegisterUser>` and anothe one is in `< uc1:UCEditDoctorProfile>`

```
<div style="width: 950px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
        <div style="width: 425px; min-height: 800px; overflow: hidden; float: left; padding-left: 17px;
            margin-top: 30px;">
            <uc1:UCEditRegisterUser ID="UCEditRegisterUser1" runat="server" />
        </div>
 <div style="width: 485px; min-height: 800px; overflow: hidden; float: right; margin-top: 30px;
            padding-right: 20px;">
            <uc1:UCEditDoctorProfile ID="UCEditDoctorProfile1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What type of validators you use? What about server side Validate event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,
 it needs to call the validation from the page event Page_ClientValidate("pwd");
the pwd in bracket is the validation group.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateUserContrlos()
{
 var isValid=false;

  isValid=Page_ClientValidate("pwd");

if(isValid)
{
 return true; 
}
else
 return false;

 }
</script>
```

call the function from the button click like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onClick="btnSave_Click"  
  OnClientClick="return ValidateUserContrlos()"/>.
```

it solved thank u all for the support..

Answer (score 0):

This seems obvious so apologies

1. Make sure that the validation group on the validators within both user groups is exactly the same
2. Make sure that the button (or whatever) the triggers the validation also has the same validation group
3. make sure that the triggering button doesn't have the `CausesValidation` attribute set to false

You could consider making the ValidationGroup a property that is set externally on both controls. Might make things clear to you all all who inherit your code

Comment: i need a server side validation,all sets correct but when i click one button also other one is validated,i used update panel and give the postback trigger but it also not working.

Comment: Ok then use different ValidationGroups to separate out the code. I don't think update panels will help as it's likely that the validators are working on the client (unless they are all CustomValidators) so update panels will not stop some of the validators being called.